# Create a News archive by year; argument year passed by URL

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I try to build a News archive with Views 3/Drupal 7.

In a Sidebar there should be several Links to the corresponding years (e.g. 2011, 2010, 2009). After clicking on a link a new page is loaded with a block view, showing all Content types of "News" and creation year according to the previous clicked. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing the basic function of the  Views module.  Take a look at the video series ["Taming the Beast"](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-views-screencast-series-summed-up) from nodeone.se